# Generate tuple of pointers

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a function similar to `printf` (variadic argument list) like:

```
void some_func(void* object, const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, format);
    int** arg1 = va_arg(vl, int**);
    char** arg2 = va_arg(vl, char**);
    va_end(vl);
    
    if (arg1 && *arg1)
    {
        *arg1 = 1024;
    }
    
    if (arg2)
    {
        *arg2 = new char[...];
        strcpy(....);
    }
}
```

I need to generate variables in a tuple to call it with because I don't want to manually create every single variable it needs (I don't want to do the below):

```
int arg1 = 0;
char* arg2 = nullptr;
float arg3 = 0.0;
other_variables...
some_func(nullptr, "format", &arg1, &arg2, &arg3, &other_variables...);
```

So I came up with the idea of generating a tuple of arguments and passing them by reference/address to the above function with `std::apply`:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
R call_func(R(*some_func)(Args...), void* object, const char* format)
{
    std::tuple<void*, const char*, Args...> args = std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple<void*, const char*>(object, format), std::tuple<Args...>());

    std::apply(some_func, args); //Call `some_func` with the tuple arguments..

    //trim tuple removing `object` and `format`
    //then print results..
    printf("%d", std::get<0>(args));  //print arg1 from `some_func`
    printf("%c", std::get<1>(args));  //print arg2 from `some_func`
}
```

It works if I'm passing by value all the arguments.

How can I pass the tuple's `Args...` by address? Do I have to create a second tuple that takes the address of the variables in the first one, and how?

Comment: why not use a variadic template in the first place. I don't understand the benefit of starting with `va_args`

Comment: I don't understand your example (also because it is incomplete) so I can't suggest  anything concrete, but here you can find a `tprintf` example which is similar to a `printf` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack. It is rather simple and works for any types out of the box

Comment: You should not provide template argument to `std::make_tuple`, its purpose is to deduce types...

Comment: printf, as well your function has the drawback of being rather error prone e.g. wrong format specifier for an argument, one format specifier too many etc. why not take a look at how they did it in fmt (https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) instead, it seems like a better way.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I can't use variadic template in the first place, because I'm calling a `C` function. I only added that `some_func` as an example of a function that I'm trying to call. The function I am actually trying to call is `PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyArg_ParseTuple(PyObject *, const char *, ...)` and that is why I wanted to wrap it with a variadic template function that calls it with the right arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you need to adapt the call to:

```
std::apply([](void* object, const char* format, auto&... args){
    some_func(object, format, &args);}, args);
```